# sending mail in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

In my web application, when user send any comments about the site the message will come to my mail (i.e., sasi@begoniainfosys.com). Ya it is working fine up to now but when I click on forward this to anyone (forward option in webmail@begniainfs.com) it is displayed with `<html><body>` tags. How can I solve this.

```
private void sendingmail()
{
    string filename = FileUpload1.FileName.Trim();
    string a = "http://www.begoniainfosys.com/Re/" + filename;
    //string emailid = emailid.ToString();
    MailMessage m = new MailMessage();
    m.Subject = "Uploaded Resume";

    if (txtdesc.Text.ToString() == "")
    {
        m.Attachments.Add(new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(@Server.MapPath("~/Resumes/" + FileUpload1.FileName)));
        m.Body = "<html><body><b>" + "The Name Of The JobSeeker:" + txtname.Text + "<br><br>" + "The MailID:" + txtemailid.Text + "<br><br>" + "The MobileNumber:" + txtmobile.Text + "<br><br>" + "The Postion Applied For:" + txtpositionapplied.Text + "</b>    </body></html>";
        m.IsBodyHtml = true;
    }
    else
    {
        m.Attachments.Add(new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(@Server.MapPath("~/Resumes/" + FileUpload1.FileName)));

        m.Body = "<html><body><b>" + "The Name Of  JobSeeker:" + txtname.Text + "<br><br>" + "The MailID:" + txtemailid.Text + "<br><br>" + "The MobileNumber:" + txtmobile.Text + "<br><br>" + "The Postion Applied For:" + txtpositionapplied.Text +"<br><br>"+"The Description:"+txtdesc.Text.ToString()+" </b>    </body></html>";
        m.IsBodyHtml = true;
    }

    string frm = txtemailid.Text;
    m.From = new MailAddress(frm);
    m.CC.Add(new MailAddress("hariq@begoniainfosys.com"));
    m.To.Add(new MailAddress("res@begoniainfosys.com"));
    m.Priority = MailPriority.High;
    SmtpClient sm = new SmtpClient();
    sm.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    sm.Send(m);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you do it now. You are only supplying a HTML version of the email body. If this is sent to an email client that doesn't support html the tags will be displayed.

Instead you should send plain text with an alternate view that contains the html. That way the client application can decide what version to use.

```
var message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress);
message.Body = "plain text";
var htmlView = System.Net.Mail.AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(htmlBody, 
                        new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/html"));
message.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that your email client isn't editing in HTML, so when you forward it, it probably converts to rich text perhaps and doesn't know about the html tags?

What client do you have - would only take a quick Google search to find out how to make sure it's using HTML for emails.

In older versions of Outlook it was Tools -> Options -> Mail Format.